# Как проверить успешно ли удалилась запись из БД и не обрабатываются исключения?

Tags: yii2

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Запросы типа DELETE, INSERT - это "односторонние" запросы. Они возвращают true или false, и это не успешно удалился или ошибка при удалении, а означает то, что запрос просто выполнен.

Что бы проверить удалилась запись или нет - можно повторно после удаления попробовать вытащить её, ну проверить кол-во записей с таким айди.
Не изучал уии еще, но думаю должен быть аналог такой функциии:

```
mysqli_affected_rows($link);// Возвращает число строк, затронутых последним INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE или DELETE запросом.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $this->findModel($id)->delete() )
{
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```